# How to show the homepage on a different url, like site.com/blog instead of site.com?

Tags: permalinks, urls, homepage, home-url

I have Wordpress installed in my root directory, so if you go to site.com you see the list of recent posts.

What I want to do is to have the homepage show a static page instead showing recent news etc (I've figured out how to do this), however if someone goes to site.com/blog/, I want to show a list of the recent posts the same way as they show up right now on the homepage.

Can I do this - if so, how?

P.S the other url doesn't have to be called /blog/, it can be anything, e.g site.com/recent/ or site.com/archive/ would also work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple page which is needed to be the homepage and another page on which you want to show your recent blog posts.

Then go to Settings > reading and set *a static page* option in front page displays option. Then for the front page select box, select the new homepage and for the post page select box, select the custom page on which you want to display all your post listings.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However on the static page, I need to disable the comments form from showing. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: If you are going to edit the html for the page then comment the line of code which is loading the comments form. You can take more reference from [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/turn-off-comments-on-pages-by-default).
And if the answer is helpful then don't forget to mark it as accepted.